# Order of columns in Pig HBaseStorage

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

Does the order of column matter while using pig HBaseStorage

```
cellref_IP  = LOAD '$TBL_CELL'
USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cf_data:cq_update_date       cf_data:cq_network ', '-loadKey true');
```

is the same as

```
cellref_IP  = LOAD '$TBL_CELL'
USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cf_data:cq_network       cf_data:cq_update_date ', '-loadKey true');
```

I was wondering if the results would be the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order of the column is important.you are accessing columns with colfamily:qualifier with loadkey.so your first column is key and other columns are respective of your accessing.

```
cellref_IP  = LOAD '$TBL_CELL'
USING  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('cf_data:cq_update_date       cf_data:cq_network ', '-loadKey true');
```

here  the order is  key, cq_update_date ,cq_network